# How do I enable the admin form for a custom widget that is called in a sidebar template, not to widget area?

Tags: widgets, templates, theme-customizer

I am developing a theme.

I have created and registered a custom widget.

I have created and registered a sidebar.

I have created a template for the sidebar.

I have created a call to the sidebar in my theme.

When I make the sidebar dynamic I can add the custom widget to my sidebar and it displays on the screen and in the admin area.

I use `the_widget('My_Widget_Class_Name')` in the sidebar template, it displays.

When I use `get_search_form()` in the sidebar template, it displays.

When I go to Customizer my widget area does not show and I cannot modify my widget in the Admin panel.

Comment: You can't edit widgets inserted with `the_widget()` or `get_search_form()` from the admin. To add widgets that you can edit to the sidebar you add them in from the Customizer or drag them in in Appearance > Widgets.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, is there a way to assign a widget to a sidebar / widget area where it can be modified?

Comment: I just described two ways: in the Customiser or Appearance > Widgets.